# repeating data on birt

Tags: java, birt

I´m developing a birt report and I need to print the data from my Data Set based on a number I retrieve on my query. Ex: the query returns only one line and one of the columns is the number of times I need to repeat the data retrieved from the query. It can be any number from 1 to 99999.

How can I do that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi please post what you have tried, then it will be eazy for u to get answers

Comment: I´m a newbie on birt, so I just created the data set. When I run the report It works fine but it shows only one line. Now I need to repeat this line and I have no idea how to do that. The number of times I need to repeat is based on a column from the database.

Comment: What is your business goal? Why you would like to repeat the same row many times? Maybe you can just use SQL (if you have dataset from database) and prepare dataset in required way (e.g. using generate_series might solve this in postgres)

Comment: I´m printing lables, that´s why I need to repeat it so many times. I can´t manage it on sql. This is a oracle database and I can´t use any oracle specific function ( like rownum or something like that ). It need to be sql ansi.

Comment: You can't use any oracle function when defining dataset in BIRT, but you are free to program any custom java code to hack this? Seems a little bit strange. In this case I'm not able to help, however you should definitely try BIRT forum here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/2/

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do would be to create a scripted dataSet and pass the data from your original dataSet in an array.  In the scripted set, you would access the field that tells you how many times to repeat and create that many rows in your dataSet, using the data you want repeated.  Now, you can simply use the scripted dataSet in your report.

To pass the data from your original dataSet, you could either use the data engine API in the beforeFactory to run the query and fill your array or you could simply bind a hidden text box to your original dataSet and put it at the top of your report to make sure the original dataSet runs first and fill your array in your original dataSet's onFetch.  Either way should work.

Hope this helps.